# Some domains receive my emails, others aren't sent

Tags: exchange-2016

I finally made it to set up my mail-server with exchange.

Receiving e-mails works perfectly, sending e-mails works not always:

When sending an e-mail to GMX, the e-mail doesn't get delivered. After a while I get following response (I guess from my own mail-server):

> Die Zustellung an folgende Empfänger oder Gruppen verzögert sich:
>   *Vorname Nachname (vorname-nachname@gmx.de)*
>   Betreff: Re: Test
>   Diese Nachricht wurde noch nicht zugestellt. Es wird weiterhin versucht, die Nachricht zuzustellen.
>   Der Server wird noch 1 Tage, 19 Stunden und 50 Minuten versuchen, die Nachricht zuzustellen. Sie erhalten eine Benachrichtigung, falls die Nachricht bis dahin nicht übermittelt werden konnte.

means something like

> the delivery to following recipients or groups is delayed: [...] This message wasn't delivered yet. It is still trying to deliver the message. The server will try to deliver the message for another 1 day, 19 hours and 50 minutes. You will receive a notification if the message could not be delivered by then.

Yesterday I tried to send a mail to some microsoft-mail (hotmail.com, outlook.com,...) I instantly got the message that I can't send mails to them. Today it worked (but I found the mail then in my spam-folder).

Mails to gmail aren't delivered and I don't get any error-mail.

Any idea what the problem could be? 
I didn't add a certificate for now to my exchange, could this be the problem?

Comment: Monitor the log files of your MTA for the actual reasons.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider What is MTA? sorry I'm just a developer who set up an exchange for the first time...(and I hate marking as duplicate before not discussed. It's a "ah marked as duplicate, thanks. and in the end of the day I don't get an answer".. )

Comment: MTA is a Message Transport Agent. In your case that would be Exchange. The linked question contains a lot of helpful information. Read it, use it, expand your question with additional information you find in your event logs.

Comment: the problem seems to be that gmx and web want to have a matching reverse-DNS. nevertheless, Micrsoft (msn,outlook,hotmail,live) still pushes my mails into junk-mail... not sure if I still missed something. anyway, thanks for the link